# What are the C++ namespaces ros:: and std::?

Tags: c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I went through the tutorials and in the tutorial on how to write a subscriber (C++) I saw a line "ros::init(...)" and "std::stringstream ss;"

Sombody knows what are ros and std? where is their location/source?

please help me,

thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41800/what-are-the-c++-namespaces-ros::-and-std::-?/) by [SHPOWER](https://answers.ros.org/users/2209/shpower/) on ROS Answers with karma: 302 on 2012-08-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ros and std are C++ namespaces. These namespaces are comprised of many different files.

std: The standard C++ library. When programers use this line:

```
using namespace std;
```

They are stating that they are using the standard namespace (allows you to use the variables without putting std:: in front of them).

For example:

```
std::cout<<"Hello world!";
```

becomes:

```
cout<<"Hello world!";
```

When mixing namespaces, it is of bad practice to do the following:

```
using namespace std; 
using namespace ros;
```

Reason being, you may overload some methods you don't intend to. You can read more about this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c).

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2012-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sunsea_x](https://answers.ros.org/users/8476/sunsea_x/) on 2014-11-27**:
thanks，that‘s all my wanted！！